# asp.net core. Возвращать статус код 401 если требуется авторизация для доступа

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть у меня такой код:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public sealed class UsersController : Controller
{
    // GET api/users/current
    [HttpGet("current")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Current()
    {
        var user = await GetCurrentUser();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var result = Mapper.Map<GetUserViewModel>(user);

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при попытке обратиться к методу `Current` неавторизованному клиенту вместо представления выдавало статус код 401. Сейчас возвращает либо странице по умолчанию, либо код 404, если такой страницы не установлено в настройкай маршрутизации. Нужно чтобы этот код возвращался для всех методов, помеченных `[Authorize]`.

Код класса `Startup`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        AuthOptions.SetAuthOptions(Configuration);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Angular5ASPCore2", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.Issuer,

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = AuthOptions.Audience,

                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AuthOptions.Key)),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };

            });

        services.AddTransient<IGenericUnitOfWork, GenericUnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleService, RoleService>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserSrvice, UserSrvice>();
        services.AddTransient<ISinInService, SinInService>();
        services.AddTransient<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

        Enum.TryParse(Configuration["LogLevel"], true, out LogLevel logLevel);
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(logLevel);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(logLevel);
        loggerFactory.AddContext(logLevel, Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            loggerFactory.AddFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logger.txt"), logLevel);
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Angular5ASPCore2 V1");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultApi",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

**update**

Сделал следующий костыль: добавил контроллер `AccountController` с методом `Login`, который всегда возвращает `UnauthorizedResult`. Должен же быть адекватный способ решить мою проблему.

Comment: А зачем? Чем 401 не нравится?

Comment: @Alexey можно и 401, но сейчас возвращается представление по умолчанию с кодом 200. Видимо где-то нужно что-то подправить в классе Startup, но я не знаю что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогает такой код (asp.net core 2)

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Да скорее всего. У вас отсутствует `app.UseAuthentication();` Вот код Startup на Asp.Net Core у меня (Должно помочь). У меня все норм:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "White Drago API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            }
        );

        //services.AddJwtBearerAuthentication(o =>
        //{
        //    o.Audience = "myapi";
        //    o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        //    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        //});

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // укзывает, будет ли валидироваться издатель при валидации токена
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    // строка, представляющая издателя
                    ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.Issuer,
                    // будет ли валидироваться потребитель токена
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    // установка потребителя токена
                    ValidAudience = AuthOptions.Audience,
                    // будет ли валидироваться время существования
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    // установка ключа безопасности
                    IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                    // валидация ключа безопасности
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

       // app.UseMiddleware<LogHeadersMiddleware>();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "White Drago API V1");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}